# Do i learn ReactJs wrong?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

After i've seen a discussion today about "dumb components and smart components" i realized that i only use dumb components?

Like in this mini youtube clone app that i made to learn and for fun.I'm starting to feel confortable with React more and more and now after i seen that discussion i don't know if i'm learning it the right way

App component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";
import Content from "./Content";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import SingleVideo from "./SingleVideo";
import requests from "./requests";

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true);

  const inputHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(text);
  };

  return (
    <section className="main">
      <Router>
        <nav className="navbar">
          <Link to="/">
            <div className="logo">
              <i
                class="bars fas fa-bars"
                onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}
              ></i>
              <i className="youtube fab fa-youtube"></i>
              <h1>Youtube</h1>
            </div>
          </Link>
          <form onClick={inputHandler}>
            <input
              className="input"
              placeholder="Search"
              type="text"
              value={text}
              onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button type="submit" className="btn">
              <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
            </button>
          </form>
          <img src="" alt="" />
        </nav>
        <Switch>
          <div className="side-by-side">
            <NavBar toggle={toggle} />
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Content fetchURL={requests.fetchHome} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/trending">
              <Content fetchURL={requests.fetchTrending} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/subscriptions">
              <Content title="Subscriptions" />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/player/:videoId/:title">
              <SingleVideo />
            </Route>
          </div>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </section>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Content Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const Content = ({ fetchURL }) => {
  const [video, setVideo] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(fetchURL);
        setVideo(response.data.items);
        console.log(video);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchURL]);

  return (
    <section className="main-content">
      {video.map((vid) => {
        return (
          <Link to={`/player/${vid.id.videoId}/${vid.snippet.title}`}>
            <div className="video" key={vid.etag}>
              <img src={vid.snippet.thumbnails.high.url} alt="" />

              <div className="info">
                <div className="channel">
                  <img src="" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div className="title">
                  {vid.snippet.title}
                  <p className="channel-name">{vid.snippet.channelTitle}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Link>
        );
      })}
    </section>
  );
};

export default Content;
```

SingleVideo Component

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const SingleVideo = () => {
  const { videoId, title } = useParams();
  console.log(videoId);

  return (
    <section className="single-video">
      <div className="player">
        <iframe
          width="1300"
          height="700"
          frameBorder="0"
          allowFullScreen
          src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`}
        ></iframe>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default SingleVideo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using all dumb components.  React has changed a bit over the years and older documentation may give a misleading understanding of how things work now. A dumb component is one that does not have modifiable state, it will render entirely based on the react properties.  In the past, when using function components with react, they were all dumb due to a lack of a way for them to handle state. In newer versions of React they introduced the useState hook that allows for function components to have state, meaning just because its a function component does not mean it is dumb. Like or hate the new hooks api, it is just a different mechanism to do the same thing and has all the same pros and cons.

The pros of dumb components are really obvious when it comes to testing. Your testing can be as simple as define the properties and then check the output.